# 'org.apache.http' is deprecated. Even After Adding Lib in build Gradle... In API 26+

Tags: android, json, apache, sqlite, deprecated

I followed [This](https://androidjson.com/save-store-php-mysql-json-parsing-data-sqlite/) to Parse JSON data to SQLite, Here I ma Using Android API 26

So Here I am Unable to Use `org.apache.http`

I Followed Many Forms and Stackoverflow Answers

I have Added this in Gradle `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` But Still Same issue in API-26

Here Every thing Related to `org.apache.http` is deprecated.

I am Using

```
 'org.apache.http.NameValuePair'
 'org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair'
 'org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet'
 'org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost'
 'org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest'
 'org.apache.http.client.parms.HttpParms'
 'org.apache.http.client.parms.HttpConnectionParms'
 'org.apache.http.client.HttpClient'
 'org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient'
 'org.apache.http.HttpResponse'
 'org.apache.http.HttpEntity'
 'org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException'
```

All of the Above Are Deprecated I followed Many Forms and Answers But I need to Modify My Code Many Time is there Any way Or Is there any Exact Document

Or Is there Any Other Way to Parse JSON Data data to SQLite Using Async...

Please Help Regarding this Issue There are Many Questions Related to `org.apache.http` But Its Answer Working Fine till API 23 But FOR API 26 Its not working

**Here I am Asking For API 26 SO Please Read The Question Before mark Duplicate/DownVote**

Comment: why dont u try Gson for parsing, much better!

Comment: just google it, its used the most. it is Google Json parsing library, hence Gson

Comment: Thanks @ Niraj Sanghani, I am Using Same to POST Data to URL and Get JSON data as response and Saving That Response Data to SQLite So Its Quite Complicated if I change 1 thing...

Comment: then dont use it at all, Use Retrofit with Gson, again google it, its very good, and requires minimal coding. has no such version issues.

Comment: are you sure that you are getting error, not a warning? If it says about deprication, then it has to be warning, not an error.